Show that the inclusion $\phi$ from $l^1$ to $c_0$ is not a topological homomorphism
Let $l^1$ be the space of absolute summable sequences, that is $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n| \lt \infty$.
Let $c_0$ be the space of sequences that converge to zero, that is $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Let $\phi$ be the inclusion $\phi: l^1 \rightarrow c_0$, such that for $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^1$, $\phi(x) = x$.
First, I was tasked with proving that $\phi$ is continuous. I think that follows from the fact that $\sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||\phi(x)|| = \sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||x|| = 1$. Then, $\phi(x)$ is bounded, so it is continuous.
Now, I need to prove that $\phi$ is not a topological homomorphism, that is, $\phi$ does not map open sets in $l^1$ onto open sets in $c_0$. I think that I need to find some open set that gets mapped onto a closed set, but I'm not sure where to start that part. Would it suffice to find a closed set in $l^1$ that maps onto an open set in $c_0$?
As an added question, I've heard the space $c_0$ referred to as the space of "sequences that vanish on infinity". Is that correct or does that term refer to something else?
Thank you in advance.

The open unit ball in $\ell^1$ does not contain any open ball, centered at $0,$ with respect to $c_0$ norm, as the latter contains  sequences which do not belong to $\ell^1.$

Your argument for $\phi$ being continuous is sound. As Ryszard Szwarc pointed out, you may consider the open unit ball in $\ell_1$, i. e. $B_{\ell^{1}}=\{x\in \ell^1 : ||x||_{\ell^{1}}<1\}$. Then $\phi(B_{\ell^1}) = B_{\ell^1}\subset c_0$, i. e. considered as a subset of now $c_0$. If $\phi(B_{\ell^1})$ were open in $c_0$, there would exist $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\{ y \in c_0 : \|y\|_{c_0} < \varepsilon \} \subset \phi(B_{\ell^1}).
$
Consider the sequence $y^{(m)} \in c_0$ defined by $$y^{(m)}_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, & 1 \leq n \leq m,\\[6pt]
0, & n > m.
\end{cases}$$
Clearly, $||y^{(m)}\|_{c_0} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$, so $y^{(m)}$ belongs to the $c_0$-ball of radius $\varepsilon$. However,
$$\|y^{(m)}\|_{\ell^1} = \sum_{n=1}^m |y^{(m)}_n| = m \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\xrightarrow{m\to \infty}\infty.$$ I. e., for sufficiently large $m$, $\|y^{(m)}\|_{\ell^1} > 1$. This means $y^{(m)} \notin B_{\ell^1}$ for large $m$.
Thus, although $\{ y \in c_0 : \|y\|_{c_0} < \varepsilon \}$ is supposed to be contained in $\phi(B_{\ell^1})$, we found infinitely many sequences $(y^{(m)})$ in that $c_0$-ball that are not in $B_{\ell^1}$. Contradiction! The sequences $(y^{(m)})$ demonstrate that the $c_0$-ball contains "too many" sequences that are not controlled in the $\ell^1$-sense. Being small in the $c_0$-norm doesn't guarantee being small in the $\ell^1$-norm. That's why you won't find an $c_0$-open ball inside the image of the $\ell^1$-unit ball.
To your added question: I believe it is not confusing to refer to $c_0$ in that manner.

Let $B_1$ denote the open unit ball  in $\ell^1$. Assume by contradiction that $\varphi(B_1)=B_1\subset c_0$ contains a ball, i.e. $U:=\{x\in c_0\,:\|x\|_{{c_0}}<\delta\}$ for some $\delta >0.$ Then the sequence $y:=\{{\delta\over n+1}\}$ belongs to $U$ but $y\notin B_1$ as $y\notin \ell^1,$ a contradiction. Therefore $\varphi(B_1)$ is not open in $c_0.$
